# Creating relations between tables PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, table-relationships

Please help me! Im creating a database to store data about patients in an A&E Department. However, Im unsure how to relate the tables.

Table structure:

PATIENTS (PatientID(PK),Forename, surname, gender, DOB, Address, History, illness, priority)

A&E (ID(PK), PatientID(FK), address, city, postcode, telenumber)

NURSE (NurseID(PK), forename, surname)

CONDITION (ID(PK), PatientID(FK) symptoms, diagnosis, treatment)

Basically the relationships between these are:

PATIENT attends A&E

PATIENT seen_by NURSE

NURSE assesses CONDITION of PATIENT

Here are the relations that need to be added:

1. Time should be linked to both Patients and Nurse
2. Priority should link to both Patients and Nurse
3. Doctors should be linked to time and priority (doctors will make a decision based on waiting time and priority of patient). There is no direct link between doctor and patients.

This is imperitive that I get these relations correct so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: What are your table structures?

Comment: I have edited the question with the table structures

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not at all clear to me. For instance you talk about patients and nurses being linked to "Priority" and doctors being linked to "Time" and "Priority" - and you write as if these are other tables - but you don't describe them.

Below is how I would solve your problem, based on the foggy understanding I have of your problem.

I don't know what A&E means. I'm assuming it's a clinic, hospital or other facility.

```
aes
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    street_address      varchar(75)
    city_id             unsigned int(F cities.id)
    postcode            varchar(10) // Whatever the size of your postal code.
    telenumber          varchar(10) // Whatever the size of your telenumber.
```

Obviously your "state" could be different. Here in the United States our states all have a unique 2-character code.

```
cities
    id                      unsigned int(P)
    name                    varchar(50)
    state_id                char(2)(F states.id)
```

You didn't describe what you need to know about doctors so I'm assuming it's the same as what you need to know about nurses.

```
doctors
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    forename            varchar(50)
    surname             varchar(50)
```

Things like: influenza, bronchitis, sinus infection, etc.

```
illnesses
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    description         varchar(75)

nurses
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    forename            varchar(50)
    surname             varchar(50)
```

I put the patient history into it's own table so we can associate multiple illnesses with each patient as well as a date for when the patient had each illness.

```
patient_history
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    patient_id          unsigned int(F patients.id)
    illness_id          unsigned int(F illnesses.id)
    qwhen               date

patients
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    forename            varchar(50)
    surname             varchar(50)
    gender              enum('f','m')
    dob                 date
    street_address      varchar(75)
    city_id             unsigned int(F cities.id)
    postcode            varchar(10) // Whatever the size of your postal code.
    telenumber          varchar(10) // Whatever the size of your telenumber.
```

Again, your "states" may have a different size id or name.

```
states
    id                      char(2)(P)
    name                    varchar(50)
```

Things like: dizziness, fatigue, sinus congestion, shortness of breath, etc.

```
symptoms
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    description         varchar(50)
```

This table holds information about every time a patient visits an A&E. Any record that doesn't have an end_time would represent a patient who is currently at an A&E waiting to be seen by a doctor/nurse. You can determine how long a patient has been waiting by comparing the current time to the beg_time. And of course priority would be entered/updated by the admitting clerk, nurse, doctor, etc.

```
visits
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    patient_id          unsigned int(F patients.id)
    nurse_id            unsigned int(F nurses.id)
    ae_id               unsigned int(F aes.id)
    priority            unsigned tinyint // 1 = Critical, 2 = Urgent, 3 = whatever...
    beg_time            datetime
    end_time            datetime
```

Multiple doctors might see a patient...

```
visits_doctors
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    visit_id            unsigned int(F visits.id)
    doctor_id           unsigned int(F doctors.id)
```

And multiple nurses might see a patient...

```
visits_nurses
    id                      unsigned int(P)
    visit_id                unsigned int(F visits.id)
    nurse_id                unsigned int(F nurses.id)
```

A patient usually has multiple symptoms when they come in for a visit...

```
visits_symptoms
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    visit_id            unsigned int(F visits.id)
    symptom_id          unsigned int(F symptoms.id)
```

Comment: Perhaps you have an email address I can explain this better?

Comment: That defeats the purpose of StackOverflow - letting many people learn from and contribute to these questions and answers. If my answer is not at all helpful to you, let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: Your answer was useful, Im having difficulty determining a relationship between each table. 

Tables I have: 


PATIENTS(id, forename, surname, gender, dob, address, patient history, priority, timeid)

Comment: In my example anywhere you see "F" it indicates a foreign key and then the table and field name it points to. For example, (F visits.id) would be a foreign key to the "id" field in the "visits" table. Is there a particular relationship in my example that is missing? Or do I have relationships defined that don't make sense to you?

Comment: how would i relate NURSE assesses CONDITION of PATIENT? 

And time(id, arrival time, expected waiting time, discharge) is related to nurse because she gives the patient a waiting time based on their condition and priority and also relates to patients. 

Same with prioirty; linked to both patient and nurse because the nurse inputs the patients prioirty and the patient is put into a priority based on their condition. 

Doctors should be linked to time and priority (doctors will make a decision based on waiting time and priority of patient). There is no direct link between doctor and patients.

Comment: is there any way i can post an image of the tables on here? It would explain the strucutre a lot better

Comment: i am unable to chat because I need reputation points or something. Is sending you my email address acceptable?

Comment: You can use something like imageshack.us to upload an image if you think that would help.

Comment: okay, what is the best method in phpmyadmin to create relationships between the tables? Should i create foreign contrainsts for each table or create the relations in designer view?

Comment: Define foreign keys and use the INNODB engine.

Comment: I want to insert values from the form into multiple tables. For example; "priority (high, moderate, low) into the Patients table AND priority table. I have the values inserting into the Patients table fine using php, how would I insert the values into BOTH patient and Priority?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question and show ALL the tables and ALL the columns you think you need. Also - what does A&E stand for?

Comment: here is a clear description of what I am expected to achieve. I hope this is a lot clearer and A&E stands for Accident and Emergency - Emergency Department in the states? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663031/php-form-submission-for-mysql-phpmyadmin

Comment: I have explained it better here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664368/insert-a-value-into-multiple-tables/14664872#comment20514308_14664872